# How to group in Power Query such that group headings show above items in the rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to convert information from a database into a time schedule by office.  Dates as column headers.

Management wants the rows to be names of employees sorted by office.

How can I make a column that has headers for each office blank across the columns with associated employees under each header?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can have blank column headers in PQ or with Tables. However, once you load the query back to Excel, you could format those you want to blank so the Font color is the same as the background (Interior) color, making them invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to achieve what management wanted, I had to switch from Power Query to Power Pivot.  Using the DAX formula ConcantenateX to return the text value to the value field.

I did learn that you can only use that formula to return a text value from the same table the formula is being applied.  So there was some merging of tables to achieve the end results.

In this process I did learn that you can transpose a column in Power Query, which also worked, but it was much slower than Power Pivot.  Especially as the timelines went forward and more data was being added.

Thank you for your responses.